# Parsing a JSON file with date format and add to list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, json.net

I am parsing a JSON which has multiple dates but they are not ordered. I want to order them and add them to a list. Now this is the complicated part, I want to order them in descending order such as that :

```
2021-02-20
2021-02-19
2021-02-18
2021-02-17
2021-02-16
2021-02-15
2021-02-14
2021-02-13
```

I do not want to add all of them to my list, I only want to add for the past 7 days. So how do I do this?

The JSON format for the dates are:

```
"data": {
    "Days": [
      {
        "day": "2021-02-20"
      },
      {
        "day": "2021-02-17"
      },
      {
        "day": "2021-02-19"
      },
      {
        "day": "2021-02-15"
      },
      {
        "day": "2021-02-16"
      },
      {
        "day": "2021-02-18"
      },
      {
        "day": "2021-02-14"
      },
      {
        "day": "2021-02-13"
      },
      {
        "day": "2021-02-11"
      },
      {
        "day": "2021-02-12"
      }
   ]
  }
```

My Unity code where I am parsing it:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using SimpleJSON;
using UnityEngine;

public List<string> Dates;

 void Start () {
        GetData();
    }

 public async void GetData() {
        
        UnityWebRequest request = await MyJSON.Post (JSONQuery);
        JSONNode itemsData = JSON.Parse (request.downloadHandler.text);
        var parseJSON = JSON.Parse (request.downloadHandler.text);
        Debug.Log ("DAYS: " + HttpHandler.FormatJson (request.downloadHandler.text)); //I am getting my parsed data here

        var Count = itemsData["data"]["Days"].Count;

        for(int i=0;i<Count ;i++)
        {
            Dates.Add(itemsData["data"]["Days"][i]["day"]);
        }

    }
```

Can I order the list based on descending order of the dates?

Comment: `parseJSON.Days` should be the array of the "days" strings. So you should be able to do `parseJSON.Days.Length` to get its length. But in order to compare them correctly, you may need to further parse those strings into `DateTime` objects and then compare those for the most recent 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do

```
using System.Linq;

...

Dates = Dates.OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(7).ToList();
```

to get the ordered list with 7th first elements based on `IComparable` interface implemented by `string`, but you better to convert your dates into `DateTime` before that to order it in more appropriately form.

```
var last7dateTimesDescending = Dates.Select(d => DateTime.ParseExact(d, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).OrderByDescending(dt => dt.Ticks).Take(7).ToArray();
```

Comment: The string ordering will fail when you reach Month 11 and 12, since they will fall in between month 1 and 2 when ordering as string. The solution would be to convert to datetime as you mentoined.

Comment: @Immorality I disagree.  In the JSON shown in the question, the single digit months have leading zeros, so the sort should work fine as strings. `11` falls after `02`.

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer. Could you please show conversion to DateTime? And do I need it to convert to date or I could just use the strings?

Comment: @Ray  it depends on the task, your string format and possible changes in the format in the future but in general I recommend to work with dates in `DateTime` format because it's more reliable and accurate. You can convert your string to DateTime by doing parsing, something like this: `DateTime.ParseExact("2021-02-20", "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: @ArtemCherevan I was so free to edit this into your answer ;) hope that's fine